# BroadcastReceivers on android 4.0.3 (ICS)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have been trying to use the `BroadcastReceiver` on ICS from a while now.
I have tried all kinds of solutions, but nothing worked for me.

Here is how my manifest file looks like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sp.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".XYZActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".ScreenOffReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my Receiver code...

```
package com.sp.android;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class ScreenOffReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.e("AppSearch", "Message");
    }
}
```

The activity class has some code in it. But now this broadcast receiver never gets registered it seems. The `onReceive()` method does not get called. I could not find any solution. All the threads mentioned that I need to have at least one activity, but I already have it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You also need to start the activity (via the launcher) at least once, otherwise your app will be in a 'stopped' stated, and won't receive any broadcasts.

Comment: If starting the activity from launcher means starting it from the app drawer, then I have tried that. But again no joy came to me.

Comment: You also have to register (and unregister) your receiver in code using `registerReceiver(receiver, filter)`. Some intents cannot be received if registered in the manifest.

Comment: But can I receive the broadcasts when the app is not running? I thought registering from code works only for the time the app is running...

Comment: Right. That is the idea here -- if your app is not running and the screen goes off, what can you do?

Comment: I am also not able to receive any other intent... for example I tried PACKAGE_REMOVED, HEADSET_PLUG, etc. How do I receive a broadcast even if the app is not running?